# SSRS Tablix strange behavior with lookup expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm seeing some odd behavior with an SSRS report I'm working on. I have a 2 tablix elements that are are populated with the same dataset from a stored procedure. I have applied a filter on each tablix based on an Active field (Active and Inactive) in the dataset. Data looks fine and until I add an expression to the last textbox column field to do a simple calculation (see below). The values based on the data expression come back correct but the tablix now shows a duplicate row for one record (last record) in the tablix that has the filter set to Active. I'm not quite sure what is going on because the data is the same hasn't changed from when the expression is not there.

```
=Fields!Avg.Value/Lookup("Low Risk", Fields!RiskGroup.Value, Fields!Avg.Value, "ReportData")
```

Update:

So I haven't solve the problem but have more information. What looks to be happening is due to the order of the records coming back in SQL and how the tablix is filtering. The "Low Risk" record used in the lookup is the last record in the grouping. My 2 tablix I mentioned previous are identical with the exception of tablix filtering on Active field. If the Low Risk is the last record in the data set there are no data issues. However if the Low Risk is not the last record that is when the tablix goes awry. Anyway, still researching but anyone has any information it would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Still haven't found the issue but found a workaround. I've extracted the lookup expression to a textbox and then reference that textbox in my tablix expressions and seems to do the trick....Still very odd behavior. I actually mocked up a simpler dataset and didn't see the same behavior so must be due to something in my dataset that I can't pinpoint.